# Why am I getting SIGTSTP error even for small inputs?

Tags: stack

I was trying to solve this problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/STPAR/ on spoj. I have written the code as per my knowledge. But, I don't know why I'm getting this error. Please help me figure out the bug in my code. Thanks in advance!!!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int i,arr[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        int temp=1;
        stack<int>s;
        i=0;
        while(arr[i]!=temp and i<n)
        {
            s.push(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
        temp++;
        bool flag=false;
        while(true)
        {
            if(temp==n+1)
            {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(!s.empty())
            {
                if(s.top()==temp)
                {
                    s.pop();
                    temp++;
                }
            }
            else if(i!=n-1)
            {
                if(arr[i+1]==temp)
                {
                    i++;
                    temp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int j=i+1;
                    while(arr[j]!=temp and j<n)
                    {
                        s.push(arr[j]);
                        j++;
                    }
                    i=j-1;
                }
            }
            else if(!s.empty())
            {
                if((s.top()!=temp) and ((i!=n-1) and (arr[i+1]!=temp)))
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
            cout<<"yes";
        else
            cout<<"no";
        if(n)
            cout<<"\n";
        cin>>n;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

The input was :
5
5 1 2 4 3 
0

Here are the input and output formats:

**Input**
There are several test cases. The first line of each test case contains a single number n, the number of love mobiles. The second line contains the numbers 1 to n in an arbitrary order. All the numbers are separated by single spaces. These numbers indicate the order in which the trucks arrive in the approach street. No more than 1000 love mobiles participate in the street parade. Input ends with number 0.

**Output**
For each test case your program has to output a line containing a single word "yes" if the love mobiles can be re-ordered with the help of the side street, and a single word "no" in the opposite case.

Comment: better to describe what your code does. I launched but it is not doing anything

Comment: Plus I am not getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an endless loop in the `while(true)` 
when:

- `temp != n+1`
- And `s.empty()` is false
- And `s.top() !=temp`

Maybe there are other errors...